# Equal Training and Testing Score for Feed-Forward Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

My simple 3-layer feed-forward neural network gives me equal training and testing score. Does that mean my neural network is too simple, i.e. I should increase the number of neurons of each layer or increase the number of layers?

Comment: Are you confident that you trained your network long enough for the weights to converge on a steady state?

Comment: Yes I am pretty confident about that.